# Why Angular.js different version has different structure?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I am new in Angular and I am going to use it with a famous PHP Framework what named **Laravel**, I downloaded some video tutorial from [here](http://p30download.com/tag/angularjs) that was about Angular, that include some video tuterial from **Lynda, Tutsplus and pluralsight** But unfortunately the code what the teacher said on that video tutorials and when I do it with the latest version of Angular, The codes not working with that version.

my questions:

1-Why library programmer change the structure of their libraries or programs? (Laravel changed too)

2-Where can I learn Angular from video?

Comment: You can learn angular from pluralsight, just run another tutorial if this is outdated. If you are new in Angular try "Shaping up with AngularJs" on codeschool, then you can try Satellizer, JWT Authentication on pluralsight, a little outdated but its not a problem to fix those small problems

Comment: The library changed either due to bug fixing, feature addition or general improvements. This is very very common, I don't really understand the question. I'm not aware on any library or framework, widely used, that hasn't been changed in some way. As for a video, google the version of it you are using or watch a video an piece together from docs / tutorials, what has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is lot of migrations in angular versions which includes some syntax changes as well

1.2 -> 1.3 ([Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration))

So just keep your self update.

Comment: The down vote was from you!?

Comment: i upvoted your question :-P
So it is from -1 to 0